# React conditional style components not working in chrome?

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to create a chat feature for my project but for some reason I'm not able to style this one component the way I want to. It appears the way I expect it to in Firefox but not in Chrome.

The effect I'm trying to achieve is very basic: if the `chat` object's `sender` value is equal to the `_id` stored in local storage, the text body should be justified to the right, otherwise to the left.

```
                {chats.map(chat => (
                <p
                    key={chat._id}
                    style={{
                        display: "flex",
                        justifyContent: chat.sender === localStorage._id ? "right" : "left",
                    }}
                >
                    {chat.body}
                </p>
            ))}
```

[image]

Comment: flex justify-content has following values, no left or right.                                                                        justify-content: flex-start|flex-end|center|space-between|space-around|initial|inherit;

Comment: so, as @Zen_Web correctly mentioned, you need either  `flex-start` or `flex-end`

Comment: @Zen_Web please post an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{chats.map(chat => (
            <p
                key={chat._id}
                style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    justifyContent: chat.sender === localStorage._id ? "flex-end" : "flex-start",
                }}
            >
                {chat.body}
            </p>
        ))}
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/